# How Chrome/Firefox handles SRTCP report comming from WebRtc connection?

Tags: webrtc, opus

SRTCP tracks the number of sent and lost bytes and packets, last received sequence number, inter-arrival jitter for each SRTP packet, and other SRTP statistics.

Does mentioned browsers do something with SRTCP reports when dealing with audio stream, for example adjust bitrate on the fly if network conditions are changed ?

Comment: Yes, handling the RTCP reports help with lip sync, adjusting for bandwidth issues, etc.

Comment: afair not every codec support variable bit-rate. For example G711ulaw uses constant bit-rate. What browsers do in this case ? Does it work only for Opus ?

Comment: Opus does support variable bitrates. Changing the bitrate in the stream is not the only thing that can be done to help correct issues in the rtcp report...

Comment: What else can be adjusted except bitrate and samplerate ?

Comment: Well, if it is an audio only call, then nothing.

Comment: I think so too. This means if I use constant-bitrate codec, SRTCP does not make much sense. Also I suspect that browsers do not change bitrate/samplerate on the fly even for Opus

Comment: I know for a fact that Chrome does change the bitrate and even the resolution for Vp8 on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Chrome does adjust bitrate and resolution of VP8 on the fly in a connection, I would assume that OPUS configurations are changed in the connection as well.

[image]

You can see the feed back on the sending audio in this image. The bitrate obviously drops slightly when using opus. However, I would imagine that video bitrate would be the first changed in a video call as changing it would have the greater effect.

Obviously, one cannot change the bitrate on a codec that only supports constant bitrates.

All the other stats are a combination of what the RTCP reports give(packetsLost, Rtt, bits sent, etc.) and googles monitoring of the inputs/outputs(audio level, echo cancellation, etc.).

NOTE: this is taken from a session created by AppRtc in chrome.

Comment: Can it be statistical deviation ? Not so straightforward to calculate number of bits sent per second. You will never get same number. For example due CPU spike, number of bits can be decreased. Another possible reason - VAD(voice activation detection). Not sure if Opus does it, maybe it can detect silence somehow and decrease bitrate. I suspect we will see something similar for CBR codec. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Looks like these stats has been collected by Bob and sent to Alice. Meanwhile bitRate of Bob should depends on incoming RTCP sent by Alice to Bob.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. RTCP flow is in RESPONSE to the given RTP flow. So, for incoming packets, RTCP is sent back to the sender.